# how modify date format using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the proper way to get the date format below using moment.js?

```
29-OCT-2022 02.10.01.516000000 AM
```

I tried the following code, but it didn't work:
`DD/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
moment().format('Do-MMM-YYYY hh.mm.ss A')
```